# Select join table fields in SOLR

Tags: join, solr

I have a SQL query something like this

```
SELECT
    P . ID,
    P .code,
    l.parent_id
FROM
    properties P
LEFT JOIN locations l ON l. ID = P .location_id;
```

I want to convert this query to SOLR query. I can join two cores by below system

```
http://example.com:8999/solr/properties/select?q=*:*&fq={!join from=id to=location_id fromIndex=locations}p_id:12345
```

But I cant select the fields of locations core.How can I do this? Your valuable suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [solr join - return parent and child document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014232/solr-join-return-parent-and-child-document)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Solr does not support returning fields from both ends of an join. Solr is not a relational database, so you're usually better off trying to not use it as one.

Instead, index the information about each location to each property, and query based on that.

If any location info changes (which it turns out, usually happens very rarely), reindex the documents assigned that location.

Answer (score 4):

You can use subquery in the fl. Something like this `fl=*,locations:[subquery fromIndex=locations]&locations.q={!terms f=id v=$row.location_id}`
More info here [https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/transforming-result-documents.html#TransformingResultDocuments-*subquery*](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/transforming-result-documents.html#TransformingResultDocuments-_subquery_)